# помогите разобрать код и привести его в читабельный вид

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

увидел такую логику в коде не совсем понимаю что она делает и как ее перевести в обычное сравнение  if else или что то подобное

```
var days = isOpened ? "" :  drinkAward.award.day! > 0 ? "\(drinkAward.award.day!) дн." : ""
```

буду очень благодарен если напишите замену этому чудовищу

Comment: Почитайте про условный тернарный оператор

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тернарник это `if else` в символах ( `condition` ? `true_part` : `else_part` )

Например:

`Если будет дождь` ? `то возьми зонт` : `зонт брать не нужно`

Поэтому можно оставить в тернарниках но разнести на 2 строки чтобы было понятно.

```
var whenClosed = drinkAward.award.day! > 0 ? "\(drinkAward.award.day!) дн." : ""
var days = isOpened ? "" : whenClosed
```

Или переделать на обычные if

```
var days = ""
if (!isOpened) {
   if (drinkAward.award.day! > 0) {
     days ="\(drinkAward.award.day!) дн."
   }  
}
```

Что соответсвенно можно записать еще короче:

```
var days = ""
if (!isOpened && drinkAward.award.day! > 0) {
     days = "\(drinkAward.award.day!) дн."
}
```

Или в тех же тернарниках:

```
var days = (!isOpened && drinkAward.award.day! > 0) ? "\(drinkAward.award.day!) дн." : ""
```

Так же, если не понятно что делает восклицательный знак в конце `drinkAward.award.day!` - это своеобразное  утверждение что переменная существует

```
var myString:String?
myString = "Hello, Swift!"
 
if myString != nil {
   print(myString)  //напечатает：Optional("Hello, Swift!")
       // принудительное расширение
   print(myString!)  //напечатает：Hello, Swift!
}else{
       print ("значение myString равно нулю")
}
```

Ну и если не понятна конструкция строк: `"\(вставит значение выражения в строку)"`

например:

```
print("1 + 2 = \(1+2)") //напечатает: 1 + 2 = 3
```

Comment: спасибо большое!